# mysqli_stmt_prepare returns false from within a function

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I am trying my best to object orientate my login scripts and checks for my website. As such, I have created a function that is called named "attempt_login". This function uses a database connection via the "mysqli_connect" function provided by a outside php file that is included and returns the $link variable.

However, when in my "attempt_login" the "mysqli_stmt_prepare" function is reached. It always returns false, and as such, the if statement never runs.

mysql_connect.php

```
require_once '../conf.php';

$link = mysqli_connect($mysql_server,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db);

if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
    //Fail
    echo mysqli_connect_error();

}else{
//Success

}

return $link;
```

And the code from the "attempt_login" that fails:

```
    $link = require_once 'functions/mysql/mysql_connect.php';

print_r($link);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

    echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
    echo mysqli_error();

     //This if statement always fails.
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,"SELECT member_salt FROM members WHERE username=?" ) )
{

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$login_details['username']);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $member_salt = NULL;

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$member_salt);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

And calling the function is pretty simple.

```
attempt_login($login_details);
```

I have tried many ways to do this, but it seems to only work when it is not within a function. Which defeats the purpose of me trying to have it in a function. If I move the error output to after the if statment, it will print:

> No Database Selected

Even though one clearly is set in the link. I also can do a print_r($link); and it does print proper data for the mysql server.

It also has the same issue with procedural and object orientated mysqli styles, and fails as well with "mysqli_prepare".

I do have mysql working on the site, but any attempts to run anything within a function fails.

I have searched for several hours on trying to find a answer, but was unable to locate anything. I look forward to hearing from you! Many thanks in advance.

~Travis

Comment: Are you passing `$stmt` to your `attempt_login` function?

Comment: @AlixAxel Sorry, I forgot a bit of code and updated my question to show it. $stmt is created within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say then you haven't selected a database.

Either `$mysql_db` isn't set in `../conf.php` or there is a typo or `$mysql_db` isn't visible in `mysql_connect.php`.

Comment: Turned out when I echo'd the config data, it printed nothing. Somehow it was unable to reach it, copying the config to the same path seemed to work. You are correct, it was unable to reach the config file. Big thanks! :)

Comment: Just wanted to add one more addition. Adding a array to the conf.php and a return function to return the database details worked. It must have been some strange out of scope error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be passing `$stmt` to your function, I would advise your read this on [scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Sorry, as I replied to your comment, the $stmt variable is created within the function itself. With the code "$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);" I updated my question to show the correction. Thank you :)